# Webpage loads keeps lagging until I reset the network adapter

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, internet, browser

Having a really weird issue with my internet connection on my MacBook Pro... pages load agonizingly slowly, often hanging on a "Waiting for..." status in Chrome. This has been happening on my wireless network at home as well as my wired connection at the office.

The weirdest thing is that this issue is temporarily resolved by resetting the network adapter. All I do is run this in the terminal:

```
sudo ifconfig en0 down; sudo ifconfig en0 up
```

The next page I load in the browser has virtually no problems. Then, a few page loads later, the problem starts happening again.

Any clue what the issue could be?

**Edit:** I should add that pings to external sites seem normal (on the order of 10s of milliseconds), even when those same sites are taking forever to load in the browser.

Comment: Does this happen only in Chrome or in other browsers as well?

Comment: Seems to be happening in Firefox as well.